# "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools" while installing itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am getting an error while installing itertools on Windows 8.

```
C:\>pip install itertools
Collecting itertools
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for itertools
```

It should install the itertools package.

Answer (score 5):

itertools is one of the modules included in the Python Standard Library, so it is not necessary to install: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#module-itertools

Answer (score 0):

You can already import from itertools directly.

For example, to use the `chain` module's `from_iterable` function which belongs in itertools, you can write it as:

```
from itertools import chain as ch
```

And then use it as:

```
ch.from_iterable()
```